# Executing multiple methods concurrently in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have the following class

```
Class Results {
    ResultA resultA;
    ResultB resultB;
    ResultC resultC;
}
```

The types of `ResultA, ResultB, ResultC` are different and cannot be fit under one class hierarchy.

I have a DAO which talks to db to get the above results

```
Class ResultDAO {
    ResultA getResultA(/*takes non-zero argument list*/) {

    }

    ResultB getResultB(/*takes non-zero argument list*/) {

    }

    ResultC getResultC(/*takes non-zero argument list*/) {

    }

}
```

I need to get the three results `resultA, resultB, resultC` by invoking the DAO methods. This needs to happen concurrently. I used an executor service and called the above three methods in different anonymous callables the following way. The reason for using callables over runnables although there is no return type is because `ResultDAO` throws checked exceptions and `Runnable` doesn't propagate checked exceptions whereas `Callable` does.

```
Result getResult() {
    List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Results results = new Results();

    tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            results.setResultA(resultDAO.getResultA(/*non-zero params*/));
            return null;
        }
    });

    tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            results.setResultB(resultDAO.getResultB(/*non-zero params*/));
            return null;
        }
    });

    tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            results.setResultC(resultDAO.getResultC(/*non-zero params*/));
            return null;
        }
    });

    List<Future<Void>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks); 
    for(Future<Void> future: futures) {
        future.get();
        /*removing the exception handling part of future.get() for brevity*/
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above implementation clearly isn't good and signifies code smell. It's not easy and straight forward to make further modifications, write tests and maintaing the code. I have included only 3 result types in the question for simplicity. But there are more in the actual implementation which is why it's getting difficult to manage the code

I couldn't find the best practices for the above problem stated. Can anyone suggest a better implementation?

Comment: Maybe there's a bigger problem with the design? If you actually have more than 3 constructs like that, I doubt there's a way to do that properly without some better refactoring.

Comment: The three results get the data from db in different dimensions. I don't think there's a way to consolidate them under one class hierarchy.

Comment: Well I didn't suggest that.

Comment: Can you point me in some other direction? I can work on it and see if it's possible to refactor.